# How can I delete an object from a nested array in JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to remove the first object from an array but somehow I am not able to delete the first object here is my code can you please help?

```js
  var arr = [
    {
      demo: [
        {
          label: "NOT - Notification",
          id: "NOT",
          subTree: null,
        },
        { 
          label: "LIM - Limitation", 
          id: "LIM", 
          subTree: null 
        },
      ],
    },
  ];
var ind = arr.findIndex(function (element) {
  return element.demo?.id === "NOT";
});
if (ind !== -1) {
  arr.splice(ind, 1);
}
console.log('this is new', arr);
```

If you have any better solution then feel free to drop will appreciate your help.

Comment: `element.demo?.id === "NOT"` -> `element.demo?.[0].id === "NOT"` if you have one item in the array or `element.demo?.some(x =>x?.[0].id === "NOT"`)` for multiple.

Comment: Use `some()` to check all the object in the demo array. `element.demo.id` does not take into account that it's an array.

Comment: element.demo?.some(x =>x?.[0].id === "NOT") with this it throws undefined error

Answer (score 0):

The `demo` property in your object refers to an array, so you will need to access the first nested object with an index, e.g. `element.demo[0].id`.

```js
const arr = [
  { demo: [{ label: "NOT - Notification", id: "NOT", subTree: null }] },
  { demo: [{ label: "LIM - Limitation", id: "LIM", subTree: null }] },
];

const ind = arr.findIndex(element => element.demo[0].id === "NOT");

if (ind !== -1) {
  arr.splice(ind, 1);
}

console.log('this is new', arr);
```

Comment: this is working Thank you. but I have edited the question can you have a look if you have any other ideas?

Answer (score -3):

This should work:

```
arr = arr.filter(item => demo?.id !== "NOT");
```

It filters all items where `id` is not equal to "NOT".